# When do functions apply on lists and when they do not

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, attributes

I have read in my lecture notes on *Mathematica* that functions (in the general sense) can be applied to lists of data and that they can return new lists with data. I have tried this and I have got these results, see following picture:

[image]

As you can see, in this picture the function `Sin[x]` works fine on the lists but the functions `Eigenvalues` and `Characteristic` polynomials they do not...

Do I miss something here or am I wrong at all?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you read https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Attributes.html

Comment: Some functions are `Listable` (which is what Bill was referring to, a bit vague....), which mean they automatically thread over lists. But not all functions have this attribute.

Comment: Also keep in mind that some functions automatically map themselves over lists, yet do not have a `Listable` attribute. `StringSplit` (and many other string functions) is a good example of this. Usually these are functions with multiple arguments where the automatic mapping is only done with the first argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with using [`Names`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names) and [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes) is that sometimes the symbol doesn't acquire the attribute until it is used. For instance:

```
listable =  Select[Names["System`*"], MemberQ[Attributes[#], Listable] &];
MemberQ[listable, "FresnelC"]
```

> False

Use [`FresnelC`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FresnelC):

```
FresnelC[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> {FresnelC[1], FresnelC[2], FresnelC[3]}

Now, check the attributes:

```
Attributes["FresnelC"]
```

> {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected, ReadProtected}

If we run the above code again:

```
listable =  Select[Names["System`*"], MemberQ[Attributes[#], Listable] &];
MemberQ[listable, "FresnelC"]
```

> True

So, if you really want a list of all listable functions using [`Names`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names) and [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes), you need to evaluate the symbol and then check the attributes. However, then you will be performing an autoload for every system symbol, which will take a while and bloat your memory. So, instead, I recommend you use [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue):

```
EntityValue[
    EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Attributes"->ContainsAny[{"Listable"}]],
    "Name"
] //Short
```

> {"Abs","AbsArg","AiryAi","AiryAiPrime","AiryAiZero","AiryBi",<<434>>,"WhittakerW","WordStem","ZernikeR","Zeta","ZetaZero"}

Comment: Thank you @Carl. (I was wondering why the list is shorter in v12.0 than in v9.9)

Answer (score 5):

The list of functions with the [`Attributes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) in the `System` context

```
listable =  Select[Names["System`*"], MemberQ[Attributes[#], Listable] &];

Length @ listable (* Version 12.0.0 *)
```

> 340

```
Short[listable, 10]
```

> {Abs, AbsArg, AiryAi, AiryAiPrime, AiryAiZero, AiryBi, AiryBiPrime, 
>       AiryBiZero, AlgebraicIntegerQ, AlgebraicNumberDenominator, 
>       AlgebraicNumberNorm, AlgebraicNumberTrace, AlgebraicUnitQ, AngerJ, 
>       Apart, ArcCos, ArcCosh, ArcCot, ArcCoth, ArcCsc, ArcCsch, ArcSec,
>   << 300 >>,
>   Times, ToExpression, Together, ToHeldExpression, 
>       ToLowerCase, ToUpperCase, TrigFactor, TrigToExp, TukeyWindow, 
>       UnitBox, UnitDimensions, Unitize, UnitSimplify, UnitStep, 
>       UnitTriangle, VertexWeightedGraphQ, WeberE, WelchWindow, WhittakerM, 
>       WhittakerW, Zeta, ZetaZero}